# How is a typed Scala object losing its type?

Tags: scala

In the following piece of code, `entities` is a `Map[String, Seq[String]]` object that I receive from some other piece of code. The goal is to map the entities object into a two column Spark DataFrame; but, before I get there, I found some very unusual results.

```
val data: Map[String, Seq[String]] = Map("idtag" -> Seq("things", "associated", "with", "id"))

println(data)
println(data.toSeq)
data.toSeq.foreach{println}
data.toSeq.map{case(id: String, names: Seq[String]) => names}.foreach{println}

val eSeq: Seq[(String, Seq[String])] = entities.toSeq

println(eSeq.head)
println(eSeq.head.getClass)
println(eSeq.head._1.getClass)
println(eSeq.head._2.getClass)

eSeq.map{case(id: String, names: Seq[String]) => names}.foreach{println}
```

The output of the above on the console is:

```
Map(idtag -> List(things, associated, with, id))
ArrayBuffer((idtag,List(things, associated, with, id)))
(idtag,List(things, associated, with, id))
List(things, associated, with, id)

(0CY4NZ-E,["MEC", "Marriott-MEC", "Media IQ - Kimberly Clark c/o Mindshare", "Mindshare", "WPP", "WPP Plc", "Wavemaker Global", "Wavemaker Global Ltd"])
class scala.Tuple2
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
        at package.EntityList$$anonfun$toStorage$4.apply(EntityList.scala:31)
```

The `data` object that I hardcoded acts as expected. The `.toSeq` function on the entities map produces a `Seq` (implemented as an ArrayBuffer) of tuples; and these tuples can be processed through mapping.

But using the `entities` object, you can see that when I take the first element using `.head` and it is a `Tuple2[String, String]`. How can that possibly happen? How does the second element of the tuple turn into a String and cause the exception?

Further confusing me, if the last line is changed to reflect the `Tuple2[String, String]`:

```
eSeq.map{case(id: String, names: String) => names}.foreach{println}
```

then we get a compile error:

```
/path/to/repo/src/main/scala/package/EntityList.scala:31: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
  found   : String
  required: Seq[String]
     eSeq.map{case(id: String, names: String) => names}.foreach{println}
```

I can't replicate this odd behavior with a `Map[String, Seq[String]]` that I create myself, as you can see in this code. Can anyone explain this behavior and why it happens?

Comment: What's `entities`??? You declare it as as `Seq[(String, Seq[String])]` but it's obviously NOT _that_. The compile error is expected: you declare it as a `Seq`, and then try to access as a `String`.

Comment: @Dima Entities is not created by me. Its type is given in the first sentence. Note where I convert it via the `.toSeq` command, and the type assigned to the resulting `val eSeq`. The compile error is of course expected, but the first exception is not. Please read the question thoroughly.

Comment: I note that the output of `println(data.toSeq.head)` and the output of `println(eSeq.head)` don't _look_ like they are related data formats. Where does the `[` and `]` come from? One has quote marks, `"`, in the data but not the other. `entities` doesn't look or act like a Scala-created `Map[String,Seq[String]]`.

Comment: @jwvh I get `entities` from another piece of Scala software; but I believe much of its origin is Java. I assumed that it was a Java Array, but that doesn't seem to check out. You've hit the heart of the problem, I don't understand what is happening. I include a specific type for `eSeq`, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @kingledion the problem is that "the type given in the first sentence" is _wrong_.
That is why you are getting the exception. I read thoroughly enough. Please don't tell me what to do.

Comment: @Dima If you are sure that this is the problem then please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that `entities.toSeq` is lying about the type of the data that it is returning, so I would look at "some other piece of code" and check it is doing the right thing.

Specifically, it claims to return `Seq[(String, Seq[String])]` and the compiler believes it. But `getClass` shows that the second object in the tuple is actually `java.lang.String` not `Seq[String]`.

If this were correct then the `match` statement would be using `unapply` to extract the value and then getting an error when it tried to convert `names` to the stated type.

I note that the string appears to be a list of strings enclosed in `[` `]`, so it seems possible that whatever is creating `entities` is failing to parse this into a `Seq` but claiming that it has succeeded.